# Why is iperf3 data transfer slower than scp?

Tags: scp, iperf

I have been measuring the throughput between two hosts connected via a fiber channel. The OS is CentOS 7.9.2009 and iperf3 version is 3.1.7 ([RPM](http://centos.mirrors.estointernet.in/7.9.2009/os/x86_64/Packages/iperf3-3.1.7-2.el7.x86_64.rpm)). One of the tests was the measurement of transfer rates when the transferred data gets written to file. This is relevant because our application is write heavy. The server was started by running:

```
$ [server] iperf3 -s -F zero.img -i 30
```

The client by:

```
$ [client] iperf3 -c server -F zero.img -i 30 -p 5201 -n 95G
```

A large file used in the transfers was created by doing:

```
$ [client] dd if=/dev/zero of=zero.img count=100000 bs=1000kB
```

[dstat](https://github.com/dstat-real/dstat) was using to monitor system resources:

```
$ [server] dstat -t -m -s -d -c -l -n 60 10
```

`iperf3` transferred the data at just about 10 MB/s.

[image: iperf3]

While `scp` was way faster (over 130 MB/s).
[image]

Could anyone please suggest what could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a known issue with fsync.

https://github.com/esnet/iperf/issues/1159

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).